# Adding sum of all the rels of the inputs. Works fine with the checkboxes, that is until select inputs are added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
            });

            $("#output").html(sum);
        }


        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            recalculate();
        });
    });
```

Here is the javascript that gets the sum of the checkboxes. Now i'm not sure how to properly add select inputs into this function. I have tried just doing

```
$("input[type=select]:selected").each(function()
```

and adding it into the code but to no avail.

Explanation: So basically everything works fine with the check boxes. The rels are added each time a check box is selected. I just have been struggling to get the select input options rels to work with the checkbox sum function as well.

Any help is really appreciated!
Thanks!

[EDIT]: SOLUTION ATTEMPT UNSUCCESSFUL

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        function recalculate() {
            var sum = 0;

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
            });

            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
                sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
            });

            $("#output").html(sum);
        }

        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
            recalculate();
        });

        $("select option:selected").change(function() {
            recalculate();
        });
```

Comment: There is no `input` element with `[type=select]` . Are you referring to the `select` element here ?

Comment: yes the dropdown form option that uses the <select> element

Comment: What lead you to the decision that `rel` is a valid attribute to use on `input` or `select` elements?

Comment: im using value for the actual form submit. This is just to display to the user which options were selected, and the calculated total cost of those. Is there a better way than how i've done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should adjust your selector so it acts on the options elements under your select instead. So your function would look like this:

```
function recalculate() {
        var sum = 0;

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });

        $("select option:selected").each(function(){
            sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
        });

        $("#output").html(sum);
    }
```

Also you invoke the function wrong - the event fires on the select element and not the option:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    recalculate();
});
```

Check out this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/9948/

Comment: perfect. What if one of the dropdown input options has a 20% off the total price coupon thing. If you dont mind. I would really appreciate if you could explain how I could incorporate that into this.

Comment: One of the dropdowns has that option, which will affect total price by taking off 20% of total including the other dropdowns and checkboxes that only operate with rel and have a fixed price

Comment: I also added  sum = sum.toFixed(3).slice(0, -1) near the end so that theres always two digits after the decimal.

Comment: this thing i added does not cause this problem its there even without it. it may be the theme im using. but sometimes when i change the selector that includes the discounts it gets stuck and doesnt update the total or even the text inside the selector.

Comment: but if i click the background. the selector updates. and the price updates.

Comment: No problem bro :) Few ideas on your issue - 1) When that happens - check your Chrome dev console for error messages 2) Make sure that your discount value is always valid (like not "undefined" or null or even some string) 3) See if your theme elements are obsuring any of those controls you have

Answer (score 1):

Form-action elements respond to `value`, not `rel` - which is BTW not valid on those.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  function recalculate() {
    var sum = 0;

    $("#myForm").find("input:checked, select").each(function() {
      sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    });

    $("#output").html(sum);
    $("#myForm").find("[name='total']").val( sum );
  }

  $("#myForm").on("change", "input, select", recalculate);
  recalculate();

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="c1" value="3"> 3</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="c2" value="4" checked> 4</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="r1" value="5"> 5</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="r1" value="10" checked> 10</label>
  <br>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <input name="total" type="number" disabled>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or alternatively you could do:

```
$("#myForm").find("input:checked, select").prop("value", function(i, v) {
  sum += parseInt(v, 10);
});
```

Comment: im using value for the actual form submit. This is just to display to the user which options were selected, and the calculated total cost of those. Is this really not possible. I would rather have the value be a text string because the cost of some of the inputs may be the same. And then it would be impossible to tell the difference if i just see the http request if im not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
$("select option:selected").each(function() {
```

`select` is not a input element.

Instead you need to iterate over the `select` elements on `change` and recalculate the sum on what option is selected.

```js
function recalculate() {
  var sum = 0;

  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).attr("rel"));
  });

  $("select option:selected").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
  });

  $("#output").html(sum);
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  recalculate();
});


$("select").change(function() {
  recalculate();
});


$("select").trigger('change');
```

```css
#output {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" rel="1000" />
  <input type="checkbox" rel="2000" />
  <input type="checkbox" rel="3000" />
</div>

<div>
  <select>
    <option value="1" rel="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" rel="2">2</option>
    <option value="3" rel="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" rel="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="10" rel="10">10</option>
    <option value="20" rel="20">20</option>
    <option value="30" rel="30">30</option>
    <option value="40" rel="40">40</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="100" rel="100">100</option>
    <option value="200" rel="200">200</option>
    <option value="300" rel="300">300</option>
    <option value="400" rel="400">400</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="output">
  0
</div>
```

Comment: May I ask how to integrate this into the code. Above I will add edit showing my implementation of this, which did not work.